# list-buckets s3api is not showing my bucket creation date?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I want to get my `s3` bucket creation dates using `s3api` . But it is not showing the creation date that it is showing in aws console.

When i tried with cli the output is like this

```
C:\Users\hero>aws s3api list-buckets
{
    "Buckets": [
        {
            "CreationDate": "2018-09-12T11:32:04.000Z",
            "Name": "campaign-app-api-prod-serverlessdeploymentbucket-"
        },
        {
            "CreationDate": "2018-09-12T10:06:44.000Z",
            "Name": "s3-api-log-events"
        }
    ]
}
```

In console

[image: this is the my aws console]

Why am i getting different dates in `s3api`. Is my `CreationDate` interpretation of is wrong ?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Interesting! I did the same and _most_ of my buckets had the same dates, but several did not. The mis-matched ones tended to be older buckets.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein is this a bug with s3api or my interpretation is wrong ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Date Created field displayed in the web console is according to the actual creation date registered in `us-east-1`, while the AWS CLI and SDKs will display the creation date depending on the specified region (or the default region set in your configuration).

When using an endpoint other than `us-east-1`, the CreationDate you receive is actually the last modified time according to the bucket's last replication time in this region. This date can change when making changes to your bucket, such as editing its bucket policy.

So, to get the `CreationDates` of the buckets that are in `s3` console then you need to give the region `us-east-1` .

Try like this in aws cli `aws s3api list-buckets --region "us-east-1"`

Checkout this [github issue](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/3597)

Comment: Thank you, this has just avoided us a whole world of pain as we were trying to order the output from list-buckets by creation date!

Answer (score -1):

This python script:

```
import boto3

client=boto3.client('s3')

response=client.list_buckets()
```

returns the same dates as the AWS CLI and `s3cmd`. Therefore, it is not a bug in the CLI/s3cmd. Instead, it is different information coming from the Amazon S3 API call. So, I'm not sure where the console gets the 'correct' dates.

If there is a bug anywhere, it would be in the `ListBuckets` API call to AWS. This is best raised with AWS Support.